# Cannot find module/ layer

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Having some issues accessing my layer from another lambda.

```
Cannot find module '/opt/nodejs/node_modules/samplelib'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/src/lambda/sample/index.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs"
```

Here is a portion of my serverless.yaml

```
layers:
  samplelib:
    path: src/layer/nodejs/node_modules/samplelib # required, path to layer contents on disk
    description: Description of what the lambda layer does # optional, Description to publish to AWS
    licenseInfo: GPLv3 # optional, a string specifying license information
    retain: false # optional, false by default. If true, layer versions are not deleted as new ones are created
    


functions:
  getSampleMessage:
    handler: src/lambda/sample/index.getSampleMessage
    layers:
      - !Ref SamplelibLambdaLayer

  createSampleMessage:
    handler: src/lambda/sample/index.createSampleMessage
```

Here is my folder layout

[image]

And here is my lambda attempting to import the layer:

```
module.exports.getSampleMessage = async (event) => {
  
  console.log(`process.env.NODE_PATH ${process.env.NODE_PATH}`)

  require("/opt/nodejs/node_modules/samplelib").test()

  console.log(`incoming event ${JSON.stringify(event)}`)
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: 
      {
        message: ` test message - the request payload was ${event.id}`
      }
    
  };
};
```